# Surround sound for cinema feature film (Pricing of Dolby Surround)

Tags: audio, codec, post-production, mixing

We are planning to shoot our first feature film with a budget of around 100'000-2'000'000$. And we'd like to master it in 5.1 Surround sound.

Normal procedure would be to do it with Dolby Surround, is there a source where I can find out how much this will cost? Or do I need to contact them?
Will it be realistic for our budget?

If not, what is the best way to make Surround sound for cinema?

We use Adobe CC and probabbly easyDCP for export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your plan is to deliver the end product as a DCP, you don't need any Dolby licensing or approval, you can just deliver the theater mix as a 6 discrete channels 5.1 mix in the DCP container.

Nevertheless, you will need an experienced sound mixer and appropriate dubbing theater. Budgeting the audio production and post-production will depend on many factors and the help of a sound person might be needed.

Comment: Thank you, yeah. We will employee a semi-professional sound mixer :) Pr professional if the budget is higher. I have a pretty solid Surround Sound setup at home, would you say this isn't enough to make the mix? If it ain't, can we mix the film at home, go to a professionall studio and do the fine adjustments there?